# Java Spring boot unit test using embedded in-memory postgresql DB

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, in-memory-database

I have a Java Spring boot project, heavily using the database (Postgres) for it's repository/data. It is the basic MVC project, controllers are all REST controllers. The project works well (service is up, able to call service via REST clients and all).

Now, I am adding the unit tests to it. I am pretty new to Spring boot and mostly the unit test part. Owing to the CI/CD (build pipeline), I cannot use the persistent/external DB for tests. Hence I need to use in-memory DB.

The initial run (Main class) runs a bunch of DB queries to build up cache while project comes up. So I would need postgres DB for testing (lots of DB functions used).

I was going through https://github.com/opentable/otj-pg-embedded which seems like good candidate.

I am trying to write the basic test as below, but it fails.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@FlywayTest
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase
public class AuthControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private AuthController authController;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {

    }

    @Test
    public void authenticateUserTest() {
    ...
    }
}
```

My test folder is as below:

```
test
    |
    resources
            |
            application-test.properties
            db
              |
              migration
                     |
                     V1__baseline.sql
                     V2__static_data.sql
                     V3__changeset.sql
```

In application-test.properties file I have following properties:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.flyway.schemas=test
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

However, when I run the test fails for Docker? Why does it searches and use docker?

```
2021-06-08 14:56:36.883  INFO 12748 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2021-06-08 14:56:36.886  INFO 12748 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in LAZY mode.
2021-06-08 14:56:37.429  INFO 12748 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 527ms. Found 23 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-06-08 14:56:37.659  INFO 12748 --- [           main] EmbeddedDatabaseContextCustomizerFactory : Replacing 'dataSource' DataSource bean with embedded version
2021-06-08 14:56:38.138  INFO 12748 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'io.zonky.test.db.config.EmbeddedDatabaseAutoConfiguration' of type [io.zonky.test.db.config.EmbeddedDatabaseAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bddef8e9] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-06-08 14:56:38.665  INFO 12748 --- [           main] eProvider$PriorityThreadPoolTaskExecutor : Initializing ExecutorService
2021-06-08 14:56:39.822  WARN 12748 --- [  prefetching-1] o.t.utility.TestcontainersConfiguration  : Attempted to read Testcontainers configuration file at file:/C:/Users/username/.testcontainers.properties but the file was not found. Exception message: FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\username\.testcontainers.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
2021-06-08 14:56:39.847  INFO 12748 --- [  prefetching-1] .t.d.DockerMachineClientProviderStrategy : docker-machine executable was not found on PATH
2021-06-08 14:57:10.598 ERROR 12748 --- [  prefetching-1] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       : Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration. Attempted configurations were:
2021-06-08 14:57:10.598 ERROR 12748 --- [  prefetching-1] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       :     NpipeSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception TimeoutException (Timeout waiting for result with exception). Root cause NoSuchFileException (\\.\pipe\docker_engine)
2021-06-08 14:57:10.598 ERROR 12748 --- [  prefetching-1] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       : As no valid configuration was found, execution cannot continue
2021-06-08 14:57:10.795  INFO 12748 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-06-08 14:57:10.937  INFO 12748 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.20.Final
2021-06-08 14:57:11.320  INFO 12748 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2021-06-08 14:57:11.583  WARN 12748 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : io.zonky.test.db.provider.ProviderException: Unexpected error when preparing a database cluster; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
.
.
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: io.zonky.test.db.provider.ProviderException: Unexpected error when preparing a database cluster; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
```

Comment: Because the library uses `Testcontainers` which requires a docker environment. `Testcontainers` starts a docker container for your test with the specific database and removes the container afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. 
1. So it means I will need docker (for windows, as my local dev env is windows) on my machine? 
2. How should it work in actual build environment (CI/CD pipeline), i.e. the build servers should also have docker in place?
3. Any other alternative to use psotgres in-memory? I have few functions which are postgres specific, so I believe cannot use H2 DB?

Comment: 1. Yes. Otherwise testcontainers will not work. 
2. I have used test containers within GitHub for our pipelines. There is a guide on test containers how to configure it. Can’t remember it exactly but it works as it should. I can look it up tomorrow. 
3. Good question. I only know H2 as in memory. Therefore I am using Testcontainers for integration testing. If you need the Postgres specific functions then no - you can’t use them with an H2 Database.